# Output Drops on Cisco Switch -- Counter?

Tags: networking, cisco, ios

I was always under the impression that the Total output drops was a counter that goes up until it resets (or maybe wraps around 4 billion).

However, this seems to indicate otherwise, or something is just messed up:

```
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 14456
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3614
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3614
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3614
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3614
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3614
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3614
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3614
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 7228
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 7228
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3614
```

Another Sample:

```
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 10908
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 10908
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3636
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3636
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 10908
ny-swstack01#show int GigabitEthernet2/0/25 | inc Total output drops
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 10908
```

In both of these examples I am just running the command over and over again, ~ second or so between commands.

Comment: What's your IOS version on these switches? They're 2960's, aren't they?

Comment: @Evan: 12.2(53r)SE -- we just updated this weekend because they seem to destabilize every two weeks, and they wouldn't show proper CPU usage unless you had a console session open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the IOS version you are using and is filed under CSCtq86186. Run a `show interface counter error` and see out the `outDiscards` looks there. It's got me scratching my head.

Comment: That seems to imply that it shows ASIC drops -- which doesn't really make sense because this goes up and down

Comment: That command reports 3673 consistently it seems.

Comment: Bug is filed as CSCtq86186